# Error while grouping data using dplyr (Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: undefined columns selected.)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data with repeated measurements and use `dplyr` in order to aggregate data.
The data looks as follows:

```
r <- rep(seq(1,10,1),10)
x1 <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
x2 <- rbinom(100, 2, 0.5)
y <- rnorm(100, 10, 5)

df <- data.frame(r,x1,x2,y)
```

Now, when I want to use `dplyr` in order to summarise y grouped by x1 and x2, I get an Error message:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(x1, x2, y, r) %>% 
  group_by(x1, x2) %>% 
  summarise(
  prop = round(length(df[y < .5])/length(df)*100,2))

Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: undefined columns selected.
```

This Error does not occur if I restrict r to a certain range using `filter`

```
df %>% 
  select(x1, x2, y, r) %>% 
  filter(r == 1) %>%
  group_by(x1, x2) %>% 
  summarise(
  prop = round(length(df[y < .5])/length(df)*100,2))
```

Could someone explain this to me and/or provide a solution?

Comment: The problem I think is here `length(df[y < .5])/length(df)*100,2)`

Comment: Unlike in some language, length(df) gives the number of columns instead of rows, use `n() * 100`

Comment: Do you need `df %>% select(x1, x2, y, r)  %>%  group_by(x1, x2)  %>% summarise(prop = round(mean(y < .5), 2))`

Comment: I just realized that using length(df) is wrong, and should be length(df$x1) in order to get the number of rows (i.e. vector length). However, it does not appear to solve the above Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do? This gets the proportion of rows for which y is less than 0.5. **EDIT** as suggested by @akrun `dplyr` doesn't really use the "canonical" subsetting(df[y<.5,]) as everything is passed through the pipe.

```
    df %>% 
  select(x1, x2, y, r) %>% 
  group_by(x1, x2) %>% 
  summarise(
    prop = round(sum(y<.5)/nrow(.)*100,2))
```

Comment: ooh, like how?!

Comment: I am guessing that it would be the one  OP intended (an expected output could have been useful)